# Two buttons next to each other in a custom wxWidgets widget

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to implement a custom wxWidgets widget in which a minus-button and a plus-button are placed next to each other.

To implement this, I let my custom widget class inherit from wxPanel, and place out two buttons using a horizontal wxBoxSizer:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class CustomWidget : public wxPanel{
private:
    wxButton* m_minusButton;
    wxButton* m_plusButton;
public:

    CustomWidget(wxWindow *parent, const wxPoint& pos):  wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, pos, wxSize(-1, -1), wxBORDER_NONE){

    wxBoxSizer *hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    m_minusButton = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("-"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT );
    m_plusButton = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("+"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT );

    hbox->Add(m_minusButton, 1, wxALL, 5);
    hbox->Add(m_plusButton, 1, wxALL, 5);
    hbox->SetSizeHints(this);

    this->SetSizer(hbox);
    }
};
```

My application is divided into a left and a right pane. I place out the custom widget in the right pane. Here is a greatly simplified version of my application:

```
class TestFrame: public wxFrame{
    wxPanel *m_lp;
    wxPanel *m_rp;
public:
    TestFrame(): wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Title", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400,400)){
    wxBoxSizer *hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    m_lp = new wxPanel(this,-1, wxPoint(-1, -1), wxSize(-1, -1), wxBORDER_SUNKEN);
    m_rp = new wxPanel(this,-1, wxPoint(-1, -1), wxSize(-1, -1), wxBORDER_SUNKEN);

    hbox->Add(m_lp, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);
    hbox->Add(m_rp, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);

    this->SetSizer(hbox);

    new CustomWidget(m_rp, wxPoint(50,100));
    }
};

class TestApp: public wxApp{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit() {
    TestFrame *frame = new TestFrame();
    frame->Show( true );
    return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(TestApp);
```

If you compile and run this program, the result can be seen in the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tt3s.png

The desired result is that a minus-button and a plus-button are drawn next to each other. However, it appears that the plus-button is drawn on top of the minus-button.

How can I fix so that the buttons are drawn next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is simply due to the fact that your `CustomWidget` never gets a resize event and so is never laid out, so just calling `Layout()` on it explicitly (either at the end of its ctor or after creating it) should fix the problem.

FWIW usually this problem doesn't arise because widgets are positioned by sizers and get a resize event when they're put in place, but as you create this one at a fixed position and it's not managed by a sizer, it never gets any size events.

Finally, I'm not sure why do you need plus/minus buttons but if you're going to use them in conjunction with any listbox-like control, you could be interested in [wxAddRemoveCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_add_remove_ctrl.html) available in the latest git master and which tries to implement the native look for all of the major platforms.

Comment: Calling Layout() in the constructor and putting the custom control in a vertical sizer solved the problem. Thanks for the help!